# Permission to change a text file

Tags: permissions, gedit, gksu

After having bought the latest Humble Bundle, I am finding Limbo not to perform greatly.

The advice on the F&Q site is

> ### Q: Limbo does not perform as well as I hoped for
>
> A: In the settings.txt file you can set the resolution and the target framerate lower. Firstly delete everything below the ———identifers——- marker and then try “use30hz = true” and a backbufferheight lower than 720.

This file can be found here  /opt/limbo/support/limbo/drive_c/program files/limbo/settings.txt

So to edit I assumed the command to be

*gksudo gedit /opt/limbo/support/limbo/drive_c/program files/limbo/settings.txt*

This however opens a blank file as below

[image]

Where am I going wrong?

```
   carter@carter-desktop:~$ ls -l "/opt/limbo/support/limbo/drive_c/program files/limbo/settings.txt"
ls: cannot access /opt/limbo/support/limbo/drive_c/program files/limbo/settings.txt: No such file or directory
carter@carter-desktop:~$
```

The file is there and looks like this

[image]

Comment: put quotation marks around the filename: `gksudo gedit "/opt/limbo/support/limbo/drive_c/program files/limbo/settings.txt"` There is a space in the path name.

Comment: No it's still blank, slightly different as it does not have the 'program' tab

Comment: What does `ls -l "/opt/limbo/support/limbo/drive_c/program files/limbo/settings.txt"` say? Please add the output to your initial question

Comment: Linux is case sensitive. Try `gksudo gedit "/opt/limbo/support/limbo/drive_c/Program Files/limbo/settings.txt"`

Comment: That's got it, sorry silly mistake on my part. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is two-fold:

1. Because you have a space in the file name, you need to enclose it in quotation marks. Either single quotes `'` or double quotes `"`, in this case that doesn't really matter. Although perfectly legal to use spaces in file names, it is considered bad practice by many Linux/Unix specialists.
2. Linux is case sensitive when it comes to file names. So use `Program Files` rather than `program files`.

This should solve your issue:

```
gksudo gedit "/opt/limbo/support/limbo/drive_c/Program Files/limbo/settings.txt"
```